# The data of the radio button is not reflected in the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I'm now trying to add a rating feature to my app.
I added a rate column to the DB for that purpose.
However, a problem has arisen.
The columns have been added to the DB, but I don't seem to be able to save them to the DB from the micropost submission form.
I checked to see if there was anything wrong with the code I wrote, but I can't think of any cause.
I would appreciate your advice.

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, '新規投稿') %>
<h1>新規投稿</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_with(model: @micropost, local: true) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "本文を入力" %>
      </div>
      <div class="micropost_rate">
        <p>海水浴場の評価</p>
        <%= f.radio_button :rate, :"1" %>
        <%= f.label :rate, 1, value: :"1" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :rate, :"2" %>
        <%= f.label :rate, 2, value: :"2" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :rate, :"3" %>
        <%= f.label :rate, 3, value: :"3" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :rate, :"4" %>
        <%= f.label :rate, 4, value: :"4" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :rate, :"5" %>
        <%= f.label :rate, 5, value: :"5" %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "投稿する", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <span class="picture">
        <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#micropost_picture').bind('change', function() {
    var size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

_micropost.html.erb

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>" data-micropost-id="<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %>
  <span class="content">
    <%= micropost.content %>
    <%= image_tag micropost.picture.url if micropost.picture? %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %>前に投稿
    <%= link_to "コメントする", micropost %>
    <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
      <%= link_to "削除", micropost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "削除してもよろしいですか？" } %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <%= render "likes/like", micropost: micropost %>
  <% if logged_in? %>
    <% if micropost.favorited_by?(current_user) %>
      <p>
        <span>お気に入り解除: </span>
        <%=link_to micropost.favorites.count, micropost_favorites_path(micropost.id), method: :delete %>
      </p>
    <% else %>
      <p>
        <span>お気に入り: </span>
        <%=link_to micropost.favorites.count, micropost_favorites_path(micropost.id), method: :post %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <p>
      <span>お気に入り数: </span>
      <%= micropost.favorites.count %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <span>
    <p>海水浴場の評価</p>
    <%= @micropost.rate %>
  </span>
</li>
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_04_24_043531) do

  .
  .
  .

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "picture"
    t.integer "likes_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "rate"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"
  end

  .
  .
  .

  add_foreign_key "comments", "microposts"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "microposts", "users"
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krmg8.png)

Comment: I created the data in rails console, and I've confirmed that the db also reflects the rate, and I'm even able to output it.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved.I added :rate in "def micropost_params" of microposts_controller.rb as follows, and it works.

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "投稿しました"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "投稿を削除しました"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  def new
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if logged_in?
  end

  def show 
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @user = User.find_by(id: @micropost.user_id)
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture, :rate)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```